# MySQL nested select query performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, nested, profiling

Is there a difference between these two queries? Like performance issues, etc?

Query 1:

```
select  i.invoice_id,
        i.total_price
  from ( select invoice_id, 
                sum(price) as total_price 
           from orders
         group by 
                invoice_id
        ) as i 
               inner join invoice 
                   ON i.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id
```

Query 2:

```
select invoice.invoice_id,
       orders.total_price 
  from invoice
       inner join ( select invoice_id, 
                           sum(price) as total_price 
                      from orders
                    group by 
                           invoice_id
                    ) orders 
           ON orders.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is have no meaning to compere their performance because they are different queries.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan no, they're not.

Comment: @Alexander, what you mean?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan look closely. They almost identical. The only differece is in first argument in the main select

Comment: @Alexander They are different, and it is obvious.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan as said in my answer, which is the right one, no they're not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me rewrite your queries without any sinifical changes:

Query 1

```
SELECT i.invoice_id,
       i.total_price
  FROM invoice INNER JOIN (
                           SELECT invoice_id, 
                                  sum(price) AS total_price 
                             FROM orders
                           GROUP BY 
                                  invoice_id
                           ) AS i 
                   ON i.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT invoice.invoice_id,
       i.total_price 
  FROM invoice INNER JOIN (
                           SELECT invoice_id, 
                                  sum(price) AS total_price 
                             FROM orders
                           GROUP BY 
                                  invoice_id
                           ) AS i 
                   ON i.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id;
```

things I changed:

- order of `JOIN` (which doesn't matter, since it is `INNER`)
- table alias (`orders` to `i`, and I really don't understand, why you wanted to name it differently)

Now, it is obvious, that the only difference between them - the first argument in the main `SELECT`. Your question could have made sence (if there was index on one column and wasn't on the other, and, dependant on the query, you would not always have used both `orders.invoice_id` and `invoice.invoice_id`), but since you already retrieving the both column for `INNER JOIN` it doesn't.

Futhermore, these queries are redundant. As already been mentioned by @valex, your query (actually - both of them) could (and must) be simplified to this:

```
SELECT invoice_id, 
       sum(price) AS total_price 
  FROM orders
GROUP BY 
       invoice_id;
```

So, no, there is no differnce in perfomance. And, surely, there is no difference in resultset.
Also, I'd like you to know, that you can always use [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) for perfomance questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query

```
select  i.invoice_id,
        i.total_price
  from ( select invoice_id, 
                sum(price) as total_price 
           from orders
         group by 
                invoice_id
        ) as i 
               inner join invoice 
                   ON i.invoice_id = invoice.invoice_id
```

is equivalent by its result to:

```
select invoice_id, 
     sum(price) as total_price 
from orders
group by invoice_id
```

Comment: Yeah? And what about the second one?

Answer (score 0):

To get the same result (if all `invoice_id` from `orders` exist in the `invoice` table) you don't need to JOIN the `Invoice` table just use query:

```
select invoice_id, 
       sum(price) as total_price 
from orders
      group by invoice_id
```